# ST7789 TFT shows blank screen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I have ST7789 display and I am trying to connect it and manage from Raspberry 4B (python). I'm currently using ST7789 python library, but anything I do the screen is always blank. Screen is only light up black by the power source, but display does not show anything.

Where I bought TFT display:
https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/32914468153.html
*(It works on arduino, but not on raspberry)*

```py
import ST7789
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import time

disp = ST7789.ST7789(port=0, cs=1, rst=25, dc=24, backlight=27, spi_speed_hz=8000000)
disp._spi.mode = 3
disp.reset()
disp._init()

width, height = disp.width, disp.height
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Draw a red rectangle
draw.rectangle((50, 50, 150, 150), outline=(255, 0, 0), fill=(255, 0, 0))

# Display the image
disp.display(image)
```

My pin connections:
`GND -> ...`
`VCC -> 3.3V ...`
`SCL -> SCLK (pin no. 23)`
`SDA -> MOSI (pin no. 19)`
`RES -> GPIO 25 (pin no. 22)`
`DC -> GPIO 24 (pin no. 18)`
`DC -> GPIO 27 (pin no. 13)`

Does anyone have idea what am I doing wrong?

I tried different code versions, but none of them printed something.

Comment: maybe you should ask on similar portal for [Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or on official [forum Raspberry Pi](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/)

Comment: add line 30, `disp.display(image)`  and line 32, `time.sleep(2)`

Comment: same, blank screen when added these two lines to code

Comment: First of all, why do you not use the kernel built-in driver?

Comment: @0andriy can you explain that a little bit (kernel built-in drivers)?

Comment: Isn't https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7-rc5/source/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7789v.c (and older version which is not recommended to use https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7-rc5/source/drivers/staging/fbtft/fb_st7789v.c) the driver for your panel?

Comment: Oh, your link goes to ST7735 panel, which also has a driver (at least fbtft one). In any case, enable it and no need to reinvent a wheel by writing this very slow and probably buggy code.